# Aquatherm - thermostat is dead. What to check?

Tags: thermostat, furnace, forced-air

(**Thermostat**: White-Rodgers 1F80-51

**Heating Unit** is aquatherm, XUAQ22-2, this is a heat exchanger hanging off a hot water heater, and giving us forced air heat for a 500 sqft space. Unit and thermostat are about 20 yrs old.)

I already replaced the thermostat batteries. No luck there.

What do I check next?

And can I use any thermostat on this thing? (I have a Nest, will that work?)

Thanks!

**RESOLVED --------------------------------------------**

Per the great response below:

- Tested good for 24vac across white and red leads
- When I shorted those leads (w needle nose pliers), the heater came on!
- Conclusion: Heater is fine, thermostat is kaput
- Replaced thermostat, lived warmly ever after

[image]

[image]

Comment: What make/model is the old thermostat? Photos of it would probably be more helpful than the furnace, you could just buy a similar one. Did you test the wires from the furnace to the thermostat, are they still good?

Comment: @Xen2050 info on thermostat added, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, check how many wires are connected in your stat. There should be 2. If so use a tester set to volts AC. Test for power, you should get 24ish volts across the two wires (usually .W and R or Rh).

If you get 0 or 120 you have a different issue comment back and I'll edit the answer.

So 24v at the stat; jumper W and the R/Rh with a small peice of wire or unscrew them and twist together. If the heat comes on your stat is faulty.

Since you already have a Nest, no point in perusing a stat repair. Now you need a common wire if there are indeed only 2 wires you have an issue. You'll need to pull another wire. That's another ball of wax covered several times on the DIY stack exchange.

Try the steps outlined above. It will confirm the status of your thermostat.

***EDIT***

Disconnect the white wire and the red wire from the wall and twist them together. After a few minutes you should have heat. I don't know why there is a wire on the O terminal without a wire on the Y terminal (unless there is one hidden) do you have air conditioning? If so Nest will be tricky if not you can use the wire conectet to O for the common.

Comment: If the display is blank and the batteries are good and in properly then the stat is dead.